# Differentiation Calculus

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

.Well, I am Confused over a problem, that I have to prove that.

Question:

$$x=a(\cos\theta+\theta\sin\theta)\space \space y=a(\sin\theta-\theta\cos\theta) $$
$$\text{Prove That:}\space \space \space  a\theta \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\sec^3\theta$$
I cant do this, Can anyone give me full solution please

Comment: Did you try to $$\text{calculate:}\space \space \space   \frac{dy}{dx}$$

Comment: Yes, I did it, but it went complicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take into account $y(x) = y(\theta(x))$
So 
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{d \theta} \frac{d \theta}{dx} = \frac{\frac{dy}{d \theta}}{\frac{d x}{d \theta}} $$
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \frac{d}{d \theta}(\frac{\frac{dy}{d \theta}}{\frac{d x}{d \theta}}) \frac{d \theta}{d x}= (\frac{\frac{d^2y}{d \theta^2}}{\frac{d x}{d \theta}} - \frac{\frac{dy}{d \theta}}{(\frac{d x}{d \theta})^2}\frac{d^2x}{d\theta^2})\frac{d \theta}{d x} = \frac{\frac{d^2y}{d \theta^2}}{(\frac{d x}{d \theta})^2} - \frac{\frac{dy}{d \theta}}{(\frac{d x}{d \theta})^3}\frac{d^2x}{d\theta^2}$$

Just calculate $x', y', x'',$ and $y''$, plug them in.